# using fovis and freekinect

Tags: ros, freenect, fovis-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find anywhere which tells me how to us fovis or viso2 with the freekinect driver. Freekinect runs and works (I've used image_view to see the various image messages it produces), but I can find no documentation or any information on how to point fovis/viso2 to the messages that are produced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142316/using-fovis-and-freekinect/) by [r2djoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/10531/r2djoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-03-20**:
Can you please be more specific? I don't know what is a freekinect.
viso2 works only with stereo cameras, and fovis with stereo cameras or kinect.

**Comment by [r2djoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/10531/r2djoe/) on 2014-04-01**:
I've added more stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

viso2 works only with mono or stereo cameras. If you want to use the depth information of your kinect, then viso2 is not for you.

On the other hand, fovis works with both stereo cameras or depth cameras. To use it with your freekinect, use the rectified topics

- /rgb/image_rect (sensor_msgs/Image)
- /depth_registered/image_rect (sensor_msgs/Image)

to publish/subscribe to your camera. Then open a dynamic reconfigure gui or a launchfile and play with the parameters until you get the results you expect.

[Here](http://docs.fovis.googlecode.com/git/group__FovisCore.html#ga113578b67d3e37bc78f1fffd8440e1ff) you have all the parameters explained.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0